# Bash script archiving files according to number

Tags: linux, bash

I am currently writing a script that mounts a samba share, rsyncs the data to a local machine and archives into a directory structure (say /home/archive/). Currently when new pdfs are added, archiving done manually which seems like inefficient use of time

The files have the following structure

```
ABC140003.pdf
ABC140124.pdf
.
.
ABC144201.pdf
.
ABC146012.pdf
```

`/home/archive/` has several directories 2010/, 2011/, 2012, 2013 etc

Basically, I need to break up the number to find the correct subdirectory to copy the file. First I extract the number

```
 study_number=`echo $file | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'`
```

Then the year

```
year=20`echo $study_number | cut -c 1-2`
```

All the above pdf files belong in the subdirectory of 2014. Within 2014 or any other year directories there are the following subdirectories `2014/Blue/`, /2014/Red/`and`/2014/Green/`. This corresponds to the 3rd integer in the number Blue(0), Red(4) and Green(6).

I use cases here to find what I have called study type

```
type_int=`echo $study_number | cut -c 3`
        case "$type_int" in
        0) 
            type_string="Blue"
            ;;
        4)  type_string="Red"
            ;;
        6)  type_string="Green"
            ;;
        *)  echo "$date: $file has unknown study type. Do not know where to place it" >> $logfile
            continue
            ;;
        esac
```

I now know the following files go in the following directories

```
ABC140003.pdf -> /home/archive/2014/Blue/
ABC140124.pdf -> /home/archive/2014/Blue/
.
.
ABC144201.pdf -> /home/archive/2014/Red/
.
ABC146012.pdf -> /home/archive/2014/Green/
```

I'd be happy if this was the end of the directory structure. However, there is another layer of subdirectories have been introduced so that no directory has more than 100 pdf files (Not my call).

For example /home/archive/2014/Blue/ has the following directories:
`140001-0100/  140101-0200/  140201-0300/  140301-0400/ 140401-0500/  140501-0600/`
etc

I now need to come up some logic such that the following files go to the following directories

```
ABC140003.pdf -> /home/archive/2014/Blue/140001-0100
ABC140124.pdf -> /home/archive/2014/Blue/140100-0124
.
.
ABC144201.pdf -> /home/archive/2014/Red/144200-4300
.
ABC146012.pdf -> /home/archive/2014/Green/146000-6100
```

I am stumped on how to logically determine that study ABC146012 should go in 146000-6100 in an elegant manner without resorting to multiple if statements for each of Red/ Blue/ and Green/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified version that needs some work but you get the idea (for a nice final solution, see @glenn jackman's solution):

Declare an associative array for the colors

```
$ declare -A colors
$ colors[0]=Blue
$ colors[4]=Red
$ colors[6]=Green
```

Then extract the needed information

```
$ study_number=$(sed 's/[^0-9]//g'  <<< ABC140124.pdf); 
$ year=${study_number:0:2}; 
$ type=${study_number:2:1}; 
$ color=${colors[$type]}; 
$ from="${study_number:0:$((${#study_number}-2))}01"
$ to="$((${study_number:0:$((${#study_number}-2))}+1))00"
```

and that gives:

```
$ echo /home/archive/$year/$color/$from-$to
/home/archive/14/Blue/140101-140200
```

(I assumed you wanted your intervals to be consistently numbered 'x01-(x+1)00')

You can create a function to simplify the process

```
build_dir() {
    study_number=$(sed 's/[^0-9]//g'  <<< $1); 
    year=${study_number:0:2}; 
    type=${study_number:2:1}; 
    color=${colors[$type]}; 
    from="${study_number:0:$((${#study_number}-2))}01"
    to="$((${study_number:0:$((${#study_number}-2))}+1))00"

    echo "/home/archive/$year/$color/$from-$to"
}
```

It needs a bit of more defensive programming-related lines of code, but it can be used like this:

```
$ build_dir ABC146012.pdf
/home/archive/14/Green/146001-146100
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot. I'm fairly new to bash and have learnt much from this answer. We use csh in our department (no longer)

Answer (score 2):

```
colors=([0]=Blue [4]=Red [6]=Green)

get_destination() {
    if [[ $1 =~ ([0-9][0-9])([0-9])([0-9]) ]]; then
        printf "/home/archive/20%s/%s/%s%s%d01-%s%d00" \
            ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} \
            ${colors[${BASH_REMATCH[2]}]} \
            ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} \
            ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} \
            ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} \
            ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} \
            $(( 1 + ${BASH_REMATCH[3]} ))
    fi
}

for file in ABC140003.pdf ABC140124.pdf ABC144201.pdf ABC146012.pdf; do
    echo "$file -> $(get_destination $file)"
done
```

```
ABC140003.pdf -> /home/archive/2014/Blue/140001-0100
ABC140124.pdf -> /home/archive/2014/Blue/140101-0200
ABC144201.pdf -> /home/archive/2014/Red/144201-4300
ABC146012.pdf -> /home/archive/2014/Green/146001-6100
```